# relation between the dimension of a span of matrices and the minimal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question**
Let X be a square matrix
$d(X)=dim (span${$X^i|i\ge 0$})

a. Prove that $d(X) = deg (m_X)-1$

b. prove that $d\begin{bmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0 & B  \end{bmatrix} \le d(A)+d(B) \iff m_a , m_b 
$ are coprime.

**Thoughts:**
a. I think the way is induction. if $deg(m_X)=2$ then $m_X=aX^2+bX+cI$ and  so $X^2$ can be expressed as a linear combination of X and I and this implies that d(X)=2. This is contrary to what we need to prove... I found a similar question here 
[Dimension of a span of matrix powers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79283/dimension-of-a-span-of-matrix-powers)
that supports my thought. I need to understand what is the difference between the questions. Is my question problematic?

b. I don't even know where to start this one...

Comment: if X=I isn't d(I) supposed to be 1? (because $I=I^2=I^n$ etc.)

Comment: Ah, misinterpreted that, I thought $X^i$ referred to the columns.

Comment: The $-1$ in part (a) is an error. You correctly thought of the identity matrix $X$. Also (a triviality) one should read $X^{0}$ as the identity matrix, I suppose.

Comment: In part (b), I believe $\le$ should be replaced by $=$.

Comment: Thanks! Can you give me a hint for starting b?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\span}{\mathrm{span}}\newcommand{\lcm}{\mathrm{lcm}}$To expand on my comments, I believe the correct form of part (a) is

> $d(X) = \deg (m_X)$, where $d(X)=\dim (\span \{I, X^i \mid i> 0 \})$.

Also, the correct form of part (b) should be

> One has
>   $$\tag{ineq}
> d\left(\begin{bmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0 & B  \end{bmatrix}\right) \le d(A)+d(B),
> $$ 
>   and equality holds iff $\gcd(m_{A}, m_{B}) = 1$.

To prove this, note that if
$$
C = \begin{bmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0 & B  \end{bmatrix},
$$
then $m_{C} = \lcm(m_{A}, m_{B})$. This is because $f(C) = 0$ iff and only if $f(A) = 0 = f(B)$ if and only if $m_{A} \mid f$ and $m_{B} \mid f$.
This proves (ineq), as $\lcm(m_{A}, m_{B})$ divides $m_{A} m_{B}$.

Because of the formula $$\gcd(m_{A}, m_{B}) \cdot \lcm(m_{A}, m_{B}) = m_{A} m_{B},$$ equality holds in (ineq) if and only if $\gcd(m_{A}, m_{B}) = 1$.