# A problem on dimension of span of set of powers of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$  be an $n$ by $n$ matrix. Prove that
$$\dim(\textrm{span}({I_n,A,A^2,....}))\leq n$$

I don't know, how can i prove it. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Maybe [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79283/dimension-of-a-span-of-matrix-powers?rq=1) helps

Comment: @GAVD That looks like it might be more relevant than the question currently being suggested as the duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

This is a direct consequence of [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem), which implies that $A^n$ is a linear combination of $I,A,A^2,\ldots,A^{n-1}$ and hence higher powers of $A$ are also linear combinations of $I,A,A^2,\ldots,A^{n-1}$.

If you want to avoid using Cayley-Hamilton theorem, you may see "[Degree of minimum polynomial at most n without Cayley-Hamilton?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1258260/degree-of-minimum-polynomial-at-most-n-without-cayley-hamilton)" and its related postings.

Answer (score 0):

As user1551 mentions, characteristic polynomial together with Cayley-Hamilton theorem will do the trick, but actually minimal polynomial will suffice, and it can be of lower degree.